# Determine struct type at runtime

Tags: c++, struct

I have `struct Face` which has a member indicating its shape. Shapes could be `GeometricShape::Tri` or `GeometricShape::Quad`. Type of shape would be known after reading some data so it is not known at compile time. Additionally, members of `GeometricShape::Tri` and `GeometricShape::Quad` should be `static`. Due to this reason I had difficulty in inheriting from a base class. Considering static nature of members and unknown type of shapes at compile time, how can I modify the code?

```
namespace GeometricShape
{
    struct Tri
    {
        static string name;
        static int nVertex;
        Tri();
    };

    struct Quad
    {
        static string name;
        static int nVertex;
        Quad();
    };
}

struct Face
{
    // don't know type during compilation.
    // GeometricShape::Tri; // triangle
    // GeometricShape::Quad; // quadrilateral
};
```

Comment: What about using a `union`?

Comment: Why do you even need distinct classes, given they're the exact same?

Comment: @David: `name` and `nVertex` are different for two structures.

Comment: @Shibli This is not a reason to have two identical classes. Just use one class and initialize with different values

Comment: Yep, what DimChtz said. How about a class called "Shape"?